# Table name having additional underscores added

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have an API that grabs data from a table, serialises the data and then sends back via the service. The code is written using CakePHP using MySQL.

When I pass in the table name (such as RX_Scaled), an error is being returned that the table r_x_scaled can't be found (which don't surprise me, the table name in the database is rx_scaled).

My Model/Table for rx_scaled is defined like this

```
class rx_scaleds extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);
        $this->table('rx_scaled');
    }
```

With the Model/Entity

```
 class rx_scaled extends Entity
 {
 }
```

My service API is set like this within the APIController.php file

```
public function getData($tablename, $id="", $filter = "-", $order = "-", $take = 0)
{
    $the_table = $tablename;

    $this->autoRender = false;

    $table = TableRegistry::get($tablename);

    $data = null;

    switch (strtolower($the_table))
    {
        case "rx_scaled":
            $data = $table->find();
            echo $data;
            break;
    }
```

(this is truncated)

The odd thing is that this error does not occur in all tables.

I'm obviously not doing something correctly, but I'm not sure what

Comment: `Table classes use the CamelCased version of the table name with the Table suffix as the class name.` and `Entities use the singular CamelCase version of the table name as their class name by default.` [Quick Example](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm.html#quick-example). You didn't correctly define table class and entity class.

Answer (score 0):

You named your table object `rx_scaleds` but then you pass `RX_Scaled` to the `getData` action

cake try not finding a Table Object named `RX_Scaled` try to inflect the name of the mysql table: so using cake's conventions `RX_Scaled` is mapped to `r_x_scaled`

So what can you do?

## Use cake conventions

Name you table `RxScaledsTable`

```
class RxScaledsTable extends Table
```

Name you entity `RxScaled`

```
class RxScaled extends Entity
```

and pass the string `'RxScaled'` to your action